# Parsing in Fragment. Application closed

Tags: android, json, listview, parsing

I cant find my mistake.

```
    public class FragmentParsing extends Fragment implements MyTask.OnTaskComplete{

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private static final String url="http://quotes.zennex.ru/api/v3/bash/quotes?sort=time";

    public FragmentParsing() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

//    public static FragmentParsing newInstance() {
//        FragmentParsing fragment = new FragmentParsing();
//        return fragment;
//    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parsing, container, false);

        ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(lv.getContext(), null, "Подключение к серверу...", true, true);
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(FragmentParsing.this);
        myTask.execute(url);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(ArrayList<String> array) {
        if(array!=null) {
            adapter.clear();
            arrayList.addAll(array);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "Сбой при подключение к серверу", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Error Logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: ru.bunakov.testapplication, PID: 29433
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
                                                                                at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:153)
                                                                                at ru.bunakov.testapplication.fragments.FragmentParsing.<init>(FragmentParsing.java:20)
                                                                                at ru.bunakov.testapplication.adapters.TabAdapter.getItem(TabAdapter.java:23)
```

Something wrong in line -

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
```

And in this line -

```
case 2: return new FragmentParsing();
```

Here is TabAdapter

```
    public class TabAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int numberOfTabs;

    public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numberOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0: return new FragmentList();
            case 1: return new FragmentScaling();
            case 2: return new FragmentParsing();
            case 3: return new FragmentMap();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfTabs;
    }
}
```

My application is closing i choose not first tab.
If class FragmentParsing is empty - application works without problems.

> EDIT: After changes requested in the comments.

```
    public class FragmentParsing extends Fragment implements MyTask.OnTaskComplete{

    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private static final String url="http://quotes.zennex.ru/api/v3/bash/quotes?sort=time";

    public FragmentParsing() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

//    public static FragmentParsing newInstance() {
//        FragmentParsing fragment = new FragmentParsing();
//        return fragment;
//    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parsing, container, false);

        ListView lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);


        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(lv.getContext(), null, "Подключение к серверу...", true, true);
        MyTask myTask = new MyTask(FragmentParsing.this);
        myTask.execute(url);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
```

Error Logs:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: ru.bunakov.testapplication, PID: 12608
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                at ru.bunakov.testapplication.fragments.FragmentParsing.onCreateView(FragmentParsing.java:48)

Line - progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(lv.getContext(), null, "Подключение к серверу...", true, true);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post the codes that you think is causing the error here. Include the error logs for the community to see what's causing it.

Comment: When you initialize your `adapter`, I noticed that you immediately pass an empty `arrayList`. I'm not entirely sure if that's causing it, but can you try to initialize your `adapter` only after you have data inside the `arraylist`?

Comment: The error you're receiving change, and it seems that it's now in the `onCreateView` of the `FragmentParsing`. Can you try to put some logs, and see if it reaches to the part after the `progressDialog` line.?

Comment: @McAwesomville ![Here's my debug screenshot](http://hdd.tomsk.ru/file/tbnllqwq) arrayList size=0! Why?? It had to be made in myTask.

Comment: The adapter is still empty. Try to put your `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); lv.setAdapter(adapter);` inside your `onTaskComplete` below `arrayList.addAll(array);`.

Comment: Let me know if it works. Or if there's something else.

Comment: @McAwesomville You saved my life!! May i ask one more question?

Comment: It worked? So it is with the adapter. I'm gonna post a simple answer. To properly close this. You can tag it as the correct answer then. Cheers! :D What's your question?

Comment: @McAwesomville I noticed that the download progress bar appears when you switch to any tab, although the download progress bar should appear only when you press the Parsing tab. ![screenshot](http://hdd.tomsk.ru/file/jmhxnbvj)

Comment: Ahmm. Sorry mate. But I can't seem to see the `ProgressBar` in the screenshot? If its the `progressDialog` in your code above. I'm not quite sure why there is a behavior change, since we didn't really modify it. :)

Comment: @McAwesomville We did not this change. But now i noticed that. May be progressDialog has wrong context? Why i see it at another tab?

Comment: I'm not so sure. Do try to tweak around which context you are using. :) I think you're pretty close to getting it. :)

Comment: @McAwesomville onCreateView method is called when it is necessary to render a fragment on the screen. I appeal to the ListView context  which belongs to this fragment. It seems everything has to be right ... Why its not?

Comment: I suggest creating a new post for this. ;) It'll be much more focused on the new issue, plus a lot more people from the community can help solve it. ;) Do make sure to include the code you think is useful. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that your `adapter` was initialized with an empty list which was causing the `NullPointerException`. Simply put your

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList); lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

inside your `onTaskComplete()` below the

```
arrayList.addAll(array);
```

So that the list will not be empty anymore before you initialize the adapter. Cheers! :D